# How to enable Area using Site Map Editor in MS Dynamics CRM instance?

Tags: dynamics-crm, xrmtoolbox

I have disabled **Settings** tab(Area) in SiteMap Editor from XRMToolbox for Microsoft Dynamics CRM/365 CE(v1.2018.7.28) yesterday. Yesterday, I could see that **Settings** tab(Area) with "disabled" status and I was able to enable/disable it.

But today when I open SiteMap Editor from XRMToolbox for Microsoft Dynamics CRM/365 CE(v1.2018.7.28), I don't see **Settings** tab(Area) with "disabled". How can I enable it?
[image]

Can anybody please suggest me?

Note: I have few custom Tabs(Area) in my SiteMap. I don't want to lose them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the xml code of the sitemap using the icon (next to delete x icon). If it’s missing there it’s messed up.

You will find the **Default Sitemap** xml in [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg334280(v=crm.8)?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#Default%20SiteMap%20XML). Refer/copy the **Settings** node. (You can take a backup of current Sitemap & Reset from “More actions” to study - just don’t update back to CRM).

You can take it from other environments if it’s applicable. Don’t forget to check Sitemap designer within CRM too.